# what is p6spy? I am getting this in the db url

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, postgresql-12

What is difference between jdbc:p6spy:postgresql://localhost:5432/{some DB} and jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{some DB}.

I set a PostgreSQL DB and DB URL was like jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{some DB} while in my properties file i got the URL as jdbc:p6spy:postgresql://localhost:5432/{some DB}.

Can anyone help me to resolve this and enhance my understanding of the above?

Answer (score 1):

P6Spy is a framework that enables database data to be seamlessly intercepted and logged with no code changes to existing application. The P6Spy distribution includes P6Log, an application which logs all JDBC transactions for any Java application.

https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy

Comment: while setting the PostgreSQL DB how I can include that in the DB URL?

Comment: When the URL is jdbc:p6spy:postgresql://localhost:5432/{some DB} P6SPY will be used